# Create a folder from text contents

Tags: java

I think this will be challenging to all and interesting too.
I have att.txt which contents 
/enumeration/unassigned.gif,/enumeration/unassigned2.gif,/workflow/close.gif,
/workflow/defer.gif,/workitemtype/bug.gif,/workitemtype/enhancement.gif.Now, I need to create a new folder called attachment inside with i need sub folders like enumeration which contains enumeration gif, workflow folder which contains workflow gif and same with workitem.How can i create in java.
Please help me as i am struggling here a lot.

Comment: add some code of what you tried so far

Comment: `I think this will be challenging to all and interesting too` - that's a BIG claim you are making !

Comment: In order to make thingies, interesting for the reader, atleast first format the question in an interesting way :-) -1, since the question, lacks the attempt as well as the effort behind asking the question.

Comment: import java.io.File;
 
public class sort 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
     try{
 
        File afile =new File("D:\\template_export\\template\\attachments.txt");
 
        if(afile.renameTo(new File("D:\\template_export\\template\\attachments_new\\" + afile.getName()))){
      System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
        }else{
      System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
        }
 
     }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
}

Comment: I Have a folder with .gif and .txt file which has name for those.gif. i need to rename the .gif with the .txt contents. Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 1):

See if it helps. I didn't got exactly but here with below code it will create subdirectories for you.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("att.txt"));
        String sCurrentLine="";
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
           sCurrentLine= sCurrentLine.replaceAll("gif", "txt");
            String[] s = sCurrentLine.split(",");
            for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            new File("attachment/"+s[i]).mkdirs();
                System.out.println("Folder Created");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I Have a folder with .gif and .txt file which has name for those.gif. i need to rename the .gif with the .txt contents. Hope it is clear now

Comment: Hi, I don't need the subdirectory to be created to the child i,e which contains .gif . Please help

Comment: Just one thing you need folder to be like \attachment\enumeration\unassigned  ? or \attachment\enumeration\ ??

Comment: Please clarify this so that i can help you out

Comment: attachments is a folder which contains 0.gif,1.gif,2.gif and att.txt contains names for this gif ,something like blocker.gif,critical.gif etc

Comment: the first code which you have given do the perfect job. But i dont want to create subdirectories for child. it sholud be blocker.gif, critical.gif etc

Comment: I Need  folder to be like \attachment\enumeration\blocker.gif....... and \attachment\workflow\close.gif...... and \attachment\workitemtype\bug.gif

Comment: So geetha above code did the same. What files you need to put inside that folders how you gonna decide?

Comment: Yes above code is doing the same, but as i said blocker.gif , critical.gif are in folder structure which i don't need. i need in image form. which attachments folder already consist of images. ITS something like  need to map .txt to attachment folder images .

Comment: Both i have stored in arraylist i,e attachment folder and .txt. The logic will be something like read the .txt and map to attachment folder .gif and create a new structure.

Comment: I have a folder called attachment which contains 5 .gif images and i have a att.txt which contains name for this .gif images, Now i need to rename(map) these images with the name present in att.txt. I have no code available. I have only the logic. Please help